# How to make a persistent call to the current RVM Ruby by Alias

Tags: ruby, rvm, shebang

The ruby shebang in several of my scripts is the usual system (MacOS) `/usr/bin/ruby`.  I use RVM for my rubies, so it's often different than the system install of ruby.

Is there a way for a shebang to contain a reference or alias of some sort, so that it always points to the current RVM chosen installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

This tells the shell to look up the Ruby in the `$PATH` which will be the correct one managed by RVM in most cases if you use RVM.

Comment: RVM is creating a huge issue.  I'm calling a script in the RVM ruby, but the `require 'clipboard'`isn't loading gems installed.  But thanks for your guidance.  The working solution was to point to the RVM default: `#!/Users/rich/.rvm/rubies/default/bin/ruby`